# Bash list comprehension or map

Tags: bash

Say I have a string in bash -

```sh
NAMES="file1 file2 file3"
```

How do I map it to the following string which I will then use as part of a command?

```sh
MAPPED="-i file1.txt -i file2.txt -i file3.txt"
```

---

For an example of exactly what I mean, here's the equivalent python code -

```py
names = "file1 file2 file3"
mapped = ' '.join("-i " + x + ".txt" for x in names.split())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use arrays instead of strings:

```
names=(file1 file2 file3)

# Add suffix
names=("${names[@]/%/.txt}")

# Build new array with "-i" elements
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
    mapped+=(-i "$name")
done

# Show result
declare -p mapped
```

resulting in this output:

```
declare -a mapped=([0]="-i" [1]="file1.txt" [2]="-i" [3]="file2.txt" [4]="-i" [5]="file3.txt")
```

This can now be used in commands like this:

```
cmd "${mapped[@]}"
```

---

See [BashFAQ/050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) regarding the rationale behind putting commands into strings vs. arrays.

Comment: @johnkugelmann They can be written unquoted, but only because they don't contain special characters – the general safe way is to quote them. No religiously strong opinion, though.

Comment: I don't write `'ls' '-l'` because I know `ls` and `-l` are safe to leave unquoted. Same thing here with `-i` and `file1`/`file2`/`file3`. That's what I was getting at.